# How do I move files from one server to another server using Bamboo?

Tags: java, unix, bamboo

I am using Bamboo from Atlassian as CI tool. I have a requirement where I need to create a new plan which helps in moving files from one server to another server.

**Why I need to do this?**
One of the server is our production server and we don't want it to contain any junk data but at the same time we don't want to delete any file, so as a solution we will move the files into different server.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: How would you do this if you were to do it by hand?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, right now I am using shell script to do my task, using the 'mv' command.

Comment: Could this shell script be adapted to be called by Bamboo?

Comment: This link helped me https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html

Answer (score 1):

We had to do something similar and ended up using a simple bash script for it (we were dealing with several directories full of files).

Bamboo has a SCP task: 
[Using the SCP task in Bamboo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-the-scp-task-in-bamboo-305759795.html)

Comment: jelle, if I use the SCP functionality of Bamboo in that case it will keep the files in both the servers, and I will have to manually delete the files from PROD server which I don't want to do, Please suggest.

Comment: Write your own bash script and have the exact functionality you want :)

Comment: Hi Jelle, this link helped me https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html

Answer (score 1):

Use SSH task to login to prod server and execute mv commands on it

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy Chystoprudov